# Variables in C Function

Tags: c, function, variables

here is the code:

```
wint_t 
__woverflow (f, wch)
_IO_FILE *f;
wint_t wch;
{
if (f->_mode == 0)
    _IO_fwide (f, 1);
return _IO_OVERFLOW (f, wch);
}
```

But why are the variables between the name of the function and the start of body of the function? Im mean *f and wch. Are they locals or global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old style C syntax.

> Are they locals or global?

They are local variables. It is same as

```
wint_t __woverflow (_IO_FILE *f, wint_t wch)
{
    if (f->_mode == 0)
    _IO_fwide (f, 1);
    return _IO_OVERFLOW (f, wch);
}
```

Comment: mh. i understand that they just the definition auf the parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is K & R style function definition.

Your posted code is similar to:

```
wint_t __woverflow (_IO_FILE *f, wint_t wch)
{
    if (f->_mode == 0)
        _IO_fwide (f, 1);
    return _IO_OVERFLOW (f, wch);
}
```

They are local to the function.